# Custom tag helper isn't interpreted on razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I try to add a custom tag helper to my project that would convert a markdown text to html. 
For the conversion I tried using both Makrdig.Markdown and CommonMarkConverter.Convert, without success, but I think that the problem lies in not detecting my implementation by the razor page.

My TagHelper:

```
using Markdig;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace CustomTagHelpers.Helpers
{
       [HtmlTargetElement("markdown")]
       public class MarkdownTagHelper : TagHelper
       {
              [HtmlAttributeName("for-content")]
              public ModelExpression Content { get; set; }

              public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
              {
                     output.TagMode = TagMode.SelfClosing;
                     output.TagName = "markdown-helper";

                     var markdown = Content.Model.ToString();
                     //var html = CommonMarkConverter.Convert(markdown);
                     var html = Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml(markdown);
                     output.Content.SetHtmlContent(html);
              }
       }
```

I've added it to the _ViewImports file

```
@addTagHelper *, CustomTagHelpers.Helpers MarkdownTagHelper
```

And that's the code using my tag helper in my view, HelloMarkdown is an attribute located in my viewmodel linked to the current view, it's a public string with [BindProperty]

```
<markdown for-content="HelloMarkdown"> </markdown>
```

Lastly, if I inspect the html code in my browser, it seems to interpret it literally, so it's the same as in the code:

```
<markdown for-content="HelloMarkdown"> </markdown>
```

While I would like to get something like that

```
<markdown-helper><p><em>Hello World</em></p></markdown-helper>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

I dig into Adam Freeman's ASP.NET Core MVC 2 book as I found Your `_ViewImports.cshtml` declaration strange looking and also found confirmation in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1#managing-tag-helper-scope) that You are most probably use the invalid syntax there.

Based on the documentation it should be something like this (note the `.`, not space):

```
@addTagHelper *, MarkdownTagHelper
```

as the second argument sholud point to either [FQN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) or the short name of the assembly and then the first argument is telling us which classes from the given assembly we want to use. Your current declaration is saying "import all classes from the `CustomTagHelpers.Helpers` assembly" which does not exists (it is a namespace). As for the 3ed part after the whitespace honestly I don't know how it would be interpreted, most probably ignored.

You can also use this syntax:

```
@addTagHelper CustomTagHelpers.Helpers, MarkdownTagHelper
```

but I guess Your intention was the first one, to import all helpers from Your assembly.

Please check it out if it would help? I think it might be it.

EDIT:

I've created a short exampe to verify and yes - it was a matter of the invalid `@addTagHelper` syntax.

After creating a new project (`dotnet new  mvc -o Sample`), creating a lib for Your tag helpers (an assembly) (`dotnet new classlib CustomTagHelpers`), adding a reference of that lib to the main project I end up with this:

```
| Sample (sln)
|- CustomTagHelpers (classlib)
|-- Helpers (dir)
|--- MarkdownTagHelper.cs (Your code with CustomTagHelpers.Helpers namespace)
|- Sample (mvc project)
...
```

and `_ViewImports.cshtml` file:

```
@addTagHelper CustomTagHelpers.Helpers.MarkdownTagHelper, CustomTagHelpers
```

After rebuilding the tag helper is visible:

[image]

Of course You can also use `@addTagHelper *, CustomTagHelpers` to import all classes fro the assembly.

And what about the default `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` which is seems to be a namespace ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers?view=aspnetcore-3.1))? This is actually the name of the dll file (assembly). You can find it here: `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0` or similar directory. Here is the source code for it: [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers). The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` is just a name of the classlib/assembly. We can also do the same trick by changing our project's structire into this:

```
| Sample (sln)
|- CustomTagHelpers.Helpers (classlib)
|-- MarkdownTagHelper.cs (Your code with CustomTagHelpers.Helpers namespace)
|- Sample (mvc project)
...
```

and then we can use `@addTagHelper *, CustomTagHelpers.Helpers`.

Comment: You're right that my ViewImport declaration is wrong, I tried many different ways to add this declaration in viewImport including now your suggestions, but it still doesn't work. How could I get the name of the assembly where MarkdownTagHelper is located? I previously thought that it had to point to the namespace.

Comment: Oh... Yes, my bad. Actually by asking You to try `@addTagHelper *, CustomTagHelpers.Helpers.MarkdownTagHelper` I did the same thing as You did - not putting assembly name but a FQN of the class (<namespace>.<classname>). Check my updated answer.